# Zend_File_Transfer w/multiple files does not upload equally

Tags: zend-framework, file-upload, zend-file

Weird title, yes, but the problem is simple; simply aggrevating.  I have a form, that I built without using Zend_Form, and it has two file uploads:

```
<input name="image" type="file" />
<input name="file" type="file" />
```

Here is the chunk of code from my controller that is handling the upload.  There's actually a little more, but this is the relevant piece:

```
$data['image'] = (isset($_FILES["image"]) && $_FILES["image"]["name"] ? $_FILES["image"]["name"] : NULL);
$data['file'] = (isset($_FILES["file"]) && $_FILES["file"]["name"] ? $_FILES["file"]["name"] : NULL);

$options = array('ignoreNoFile' => TRUE);
$upload = new Zend_File_Transfer();

$upload->setOptions($options)
       ->addFilter('Rename', array('target' => RESOURCES_IMG . $data['image'], 'overwrite' => TRUE), 'image')
       ->addFilter('Rename', array('target' => RESOURCES_FILES . $data['file'], 'overwrite' => TRUE), 'file')
       ->addValidator('ImageSize', false, array('minwidth'  => 100,
                                                'maxwidth'  => 100,
                                                'minheight' => 100,
                                                'maxheight' => 100), 'image')
       ->addValidator('Extension', false, 'jpg', 'image');

if (!$upload->isValid())
{
 echo '<h1>Oops</h1><p>Please correct the following errors: <hr /></p>';

 foreach ($upload->getMessages() as $key => $val)
 {
  echo '<p><strong>' . $key . '</strong><br />' . $val . '</p>';
 }
 die;
}
else
{
 $upload->receive();
} // if (!$upload->isValid())
```

It's pretty straight forward.  The $data stuff is just me grabbing the filename if it's there or setting the variable to NULL.  I have my addFilter() and addValidator() segmented out to only affect their relevant files in this case "image" or "file" - the names of the form fields.

The "file" upload always works!  However, the "image" upload doesn't and what's more it puts the temporary file into the RESOURCES_FILES directory which makes no sense at all.  So that directory has PDFs and whatever else in addition to files like php8TJT13, phpXmOzQM, etc.

I have been staring at this code and searching through Stack Overflow and whatever Google will turn up and I can't find anyone having this problem.  Help!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Alright, so I did more digging and it turns out there may be an issue with the way I was chaining `addFilter()` so I decided to move in a different direction, trying to isolate each file and handle it's upload individually.  So far it appears to be working.  Here is the revised code:

```
$data['image'] = (isset($_FILES["image"]) && $_FILES["image"]["name"] ? $_FILES["image"]["name"] : NULL);
$data['file'] = (isset($_FILES["file"]) && $_FILES["file"]["name"] ? $_FILES["file"]["name"] : NULL);

$upload = new Zend_File_Transfer();

$files = $upload->getFileInfo();

$options = array('ignoreNoFile' => TRUE);
$upload->setOptions($options);

foreach ($files as $field => $contents)
{
 if(!strlen($contents["name"]))
 {
  continue;
 }

 // upload instructions for image
 if ($field == 'image')
 {
  $upload->addFilter('Rename', array('target' => RESOURCES_IMG . $data['image'], 'overwrite' => TRUE), 'image')
         ->addValidator('ImageSize', false, array('minwidth'  => 100,
                                                  'maxwidth'  => 100,
                                                  'minheight' => 100,
                                                  'maxheight' => 100), 'image')
         ->addValidator('Extension', false, 'jpg', 'image');
 }

 // upload instructions for file
 if ($field == 'file')
 {
  $upload->addFilter('Rename', array('target' => RESOURCES_FILES . $data['file'], 'overwrite' => TRUE), 'file');
 }

 if(!$upload->receive($field)) {
  echo '<h1>Oops</h1><p>Please correct the following errors: <hr /></p>';

  foreach ($upload->getMessages() as $key => $val)
  {
   echo '<p><strong>' . $key . '</strong><br />' . $val . '</p>';
  }
  die;
  //return;
 }
} // foreach
```

### Pseudo Explanation

I use the `getFileInfo()` to grab an array of the files available to me then I loop over each.  At the beginning of my first `for` loop I check to see if this file has a name, if it doesn't have a name I assume that field was left blank and is `NULL` so I tell the loop to skip over that and `continue`.

Once I'm in the loop I'm just matching my upload directives with the appropriate form field using a simple conditional.  The rest should be fairly self-explanatory if you're into Zend stuff.

Hopefully this helps someone else that was in my predicament.  If you are a Zend guru maybe you can comment on my solution or fix the bug that's causing the issue.  There may be a more "Zend" way of doing it, but it's working now and that feels damn good.

### References

Why I thought it was the chaining of the `addFilter()` method, see the note under Example #3 (below):

*Note: Note that even though setting the same filter multiple times is allowed, doing so can lead to issues when using different options for the same filter.*

http://framework.zend.com/manual/1.11/en/zend.file.transfer.filters.html

A random blog article that inspired me to try isolating each, I'm calling it, "upload directive" although I'm not sure if that's what it's called:

http://www.pc-freak.net/blog/tag/uploading-multiple-files-from-a-form-with-zend-framework-zf-storing-uploaded-zf-files-with-unique-name/

Comment: Thanks; this was helpful to me. I've had the same problem with `addFilter()` - to the point that I had to fall back temporarily to using `setDestination()` until I figured this out. Also, this is (annoyingly) one of the few examples one can find of an actual use of `setOptions()`. Much appreciated.